# How to display the results of an API query in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I'm expecting to get the celebrities birthday onto the page:

```
<script>
    let count = 0

function buttonadder(){count += 1;}

    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let footprint;
    onMount(async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
            'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/celebrity?name=madonna',
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'X-Api-Key': 'apikeygoeshere',
                },
            }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        footprint = data.results;
    });
</script>
<div>
    {#if footprint}
        <p>The celebrities birthday is {footprint}</p>
    {:else}
        <p>loading.....</p>
    {/if}
</div>





<h1>Welcome to Celebrity Guide</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="/about">our about page</a> to learn more.</p>
<button>Click to close</button>
<button on:click={buttonadder} class="big">Click to add number {count}</button>

<style>
.big {
font-size: 2rem;
}
</style>
```

I can see the problem is in the "footprint = data.results;". I've tried data.birthday and data.[0].birthday but nothing seems to work.

[image] The console is showing this. How do I get it to display the birthday? Thanks so much in advance for any help, complete newbie to code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `data[0].birthday`, if the API is guaranteed to return at least one result.